# Precision and Recall computation for different group sizes

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, information-retrieval, precision-recall

I didn't find an answer for this question anywhere, so I hope someone here could help me and also other people with the same problem.

Suppose that I have ***1000 Positive samples*** and ***1500 Negative samples***.

Now, suppose that there are ***950 True Positives*** (positive samples correctly classified as positive) and ***100 False Positives*** (negative samples incorrectly classified as positive).

Should I use these raw numbers to compute the ***Precision***, or should I consider the different group sizes?

In other words, should my precision be:

***TruePositive / (TruePositive + FalsePositive)*** = 950 / (950 + 100) = 90.476%

**OR** should it be:

***(TruePositive / 1000) / [(TruePositive / 1000) + (FalsePositive / 1500)]*** = 0.95 / (0.95 + 0.067) = 93.44%

In the first calculation, I took the raw numbers without any consideration to the amount of samples in each group, while in the second calculation, I used the proportions of each measure to its corresponding group, to remove the bias caused by the groups' different size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the stated question: by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), precision is computed by the first formula: TP/(TP+FP).

However, it doesn't mean that you have to use this formula, i.e. precision measure. There are many other measures, look at the table on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) and choose the one most suited for your task.

For example, [positive likelihood ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_likelihood_ratio) seems to be the most similar to your second formula.